# Displaying Navbar and Logo contained in Header

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am really new to HTML, CSS and javascript. I am trying to display a logo and navbar flyout all within the header. Can someone tell me how to contain the logo within the header and why the flyout wont show when the screen is re-sized?
If someone could provide me with some direction that would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("navbar");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
} else {
        x.className = "topnav";
}
}
function outputUpdate(vol) {
    document.querySelector('#volume').value = vol;

}
```

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav article ads" "footer footer footer";
    grid-template-rows: 60px 1fr 60px;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}

#pageHeader {
    grid-area: header;
    position: relative;
    align-content: space-between;
    display: inline-block;
    object-fit: contain;
}

img{height: 100%;
    width:100%;
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    top: 0;
}


.topnav {
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    right: 0px;
}

    .topnav a {
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: #ff6a00;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 14px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 30px;
    }

        .topnav a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
        display: none;
    }

    .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }

        .topnav.responsive a.icon {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }

        .topnav.responsive a {
            float: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: left;
            position: absolute;
        }
}

#pageFooter {
    grid-area: footer;
}

#mainArticle {
    grid-area: article;
}

#mainNav {
    grid-area: nav;
}

#siteAds {
    grid-area: ads;
}

header, footer, article, nav, div {
    padding: 20px;
    background: gold;
    display:inline-block;

}

.form {
    font: 95% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: inherit;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 16px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
}

    .form h1 {
        width: auto;
        background: #43D1AF;
        padding: 20px 0;
        font-size: 140%;
        font-weight: 300;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        margin: -16px -16px 16px -16px;
    }

    .form input[type="text"],
    .form input[type="email"],
    .form input[type="number"],
    .form textarea,
    .form select {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.30s ease-in-out;
        outline: none;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
        margin-bottom: 4%;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 3%;
        color: #555;
        font: 95% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

        .form input[type="text"]:focus,
        .form input[type="email"]:focus,
        .form input[type="number"]:focus,
        .form textarea:focus,
        .form select:focus {
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px #43D1AF;
            padding: 3%;
            border: 1px solid #43D1AF;
        }

    .form input[type="submit"],
    .form input[type="button"] {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 3%;
        background: #43D1AF;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #30C29E;
        border-top-style: none;
        border-right-style: none;
        border-left-style: none;
        color: #fff;
    }

        .form input[type="submit"]:hover,
        .form input[type="button"]:hover {
            background: #2EBC99;
        }

.rangeslider__ruler:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 
         
    <header id="pageHeader">
    <h1>
        <img src="Images/logo.png" height="30" width="30" float="left"/> Melbourne Public Library </h1>
       
         <span class="topnav" id="navbar">
 
            <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
            <a href="Survey.html">Survey</a>
            <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="SiteMap.html">Site Map</a>
            <a href="SurveyResponse.html">SurveyResponse.html</a> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
        </span>
    </header>
    <article id="mainArticle">
        <img src="Images/image1.jpg"/></article>
    <nav id="mainNav">Nav</nav>
    <div id="siteAds">Ads</div>
    <footer id="pageFooter">Footer</footer>


    
</body>
</html>
```

The Flyout seems to be hidden or contained in the header?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make the `pageHeader` width 100% and also give a fixed display for the `img`

```
#pageHeader {
   width:100%;
}

img {
   position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Well i am sorry then but the Question is really messy and not clear. Try to edit it to make it easier for others to see your code :)